# Calculus rates question. - An aircraft flying at 450 ft/s

Tags: calculus

An aricraft is flying at 450 ft/s with an elevation of 155 ft from the ground, on a straight-line path that will take it directly over an anti-aircraft gun. How fast, in radians per second, will the gun have to turn to accurately track the aircraft when the plane is:

[image]

An picture is given by the question.

1000 feet away = ______
100 feet away = ______

Please help! I have no idea where to start. Thank you!

Comment: Draw a picture.  Label the parts you know, and the parts that are needed by the problem.

Comment: Nice picture! Can you find a relation between $x$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I don't know where should I begin with this question.

Comment: Start by putting on some of the things you know, and maybe a couple of things you don't know directly but suspect you can figure out?

Comment: *Au contraire*, you have already begun.  Find an equation that has $x$ and $\theta$ in it.  I see the picture has a triangle in it.  Is that useful?  Have you used all the information given in the statement of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establish the equation below

$$\tan\theta= \frac hx $$

Take the time derivatives of both sides

$$\sec^2\theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}= -\frac{h}{x^2} \frac{dx}{dt} $$

Then, use $\sec \theta= \sqrt{h^2+x^2}/x$ to simplify the above expression

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}= -\frac{h}{x^2+h^2} \frac{dx}{dt} $$

Now, plug in the givens, i.e. $dx/dt= -450$, $h=155$ and $x=1000$ to obtain the rate of change for the angle $d\theta/dt$.

At 1000 ft away, the rate of angle change is

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}= -\frac{155}{1000^2+155^2} (-450)=0.068 \>\text{rad/s} $$

Comment: Thank you Quanto!

Comment: @Donald Zou - You are welcome

Comment: Why the dx/dt is negative?

Comment: @Donald Zou - Because the plane flies towards the gun, x decreasing